# Reference Resource in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to reference a JSON list in the Resources group from a SwiftUI view, but it won't work for some reason. Here is the code in ContentView.swift:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var kitten : Kitten
    let stuff = ["this","that","these"]
    @State private var i = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Placeholder")
            Button(action: {
                self.i = (self.i+1)%3
            // Do something
            }) {
                Text(stuff[i])
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView(kitten:kittens[0])
    }
}
```

and my directory structure looks like this:

```
Project\
  AppleDelegate.swift
  SceneDelegateView.swift
  ContentView.swift
  Models\
    Kitten.swift
  Resources\
    kittens.json
```

along with the other boiler plate stuff. I thought that if I had kittens.json in the Resources group that I would be able to reference it in the ContentView.swift file, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you have to load it explicitly using Bundle, like below

`String(contentsOf: Bundle.main.url(forResource: stuff[i], withExtension: "json"))`

Comment: can you explain how this tutorial was able to get around that then? They have a file structure similar to mind but don't seen to have to use the Bundle like you are suggesting. 
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/building-lists-and-navigation

Comment: @nbk, aha... that is different - they decoded JSON into model... see Model/Data.swift, they use almost the same `Data(contentsOf:)`.

Comment: awesome, that is very helpful thanks! Do you know if there is a resource anywhere where I can read about decoding JSON into model?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle json files is to add them in your Assets, as a Data Set:

1- Open your Assets.xcassets.

2- You create a New Data Set and give it a name like "kittens"
[image]

3- Drag & drop your json file into that new Data Set

4- You can access your data like this:

```
guard let assets = NSDataAsset(name: "kittens") else {
      print("Missing data asset: kittens")
}
let kittens = try! JSONDecoder().decode([kitten].self, from: assets.data)
```